# Why is the button size for column toggle smaller than other buttons?

Tags: button

I have been using Bootstrap Table for numerous tables but have never required the column toggle until now for my latest table. When I add it along with other buttons the column toggle button is smaller than the rest. Any help to rectify this issue would be greatly appreciated.

You can find the issue here on this test page: https://rewardscanada.ca/newcompare.html

There is a screenshot attached as well [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8KID.png)

I've tried different browsers and the issue seems to arise in all of them. I tried searching the CSS for the icon details to see if the issue was there but could not find the corresponding icon.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `div` it's contained in is styled with `class="keep-open btn-group"` which is giving it a `margin-bottom` of 10 pixels:  [image]

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. I wish I could remember why I added the margin-bottom to the stylesheet!